# Fatal error while: sudo pecl install mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, fatal-error, pecl, macos-mojave

I have problem to install mongodb with pecl. After `sudo pecl install mongodb` it's always give me

> fatal error: 'php.h' file not found #include
>
> 1 error generated. make: *** [php_phongo.lo] Error 1 ERROR: 'make'
>   failed

System MacOS Mojave, Xcode was updated

Thanks!

Comment: Install the php-dev package for your operating system.

Comment: thanks for answer :) 

I tried to instal php once again with brew, but I have now such problem:

`brew tap homebrew/dupes
Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was probably that I install oldest version PHP than was installed on my mac, after changing php source in terminal to one from MAMP Pro, MongoDB was installed without problems

Answer (score 1):

This happens when we try to install mongodb driver on the default PHP installation on MacOS. To fix this issue we should first change the PHP from default macOS PHP o our installed version.

Run the command: `which php` to see the PHP being used. If the output is *usr/bin/php* then it is the default PHP.

Then open your bash_profile file, using any code editor, and add the following line to it, where you must provide path to your PHP installation.

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.1/bin:$PATH
```

In my case it was MAMP's PHP, then run `source ~/.bash_profile` to load your bash profile changes.

Now when you will run `which php` command, you will see the path of your PHP installation.

Now, if you try to install any PHP module using the `pecl` command, it should run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the installer can't find the "php.h file". Symlink the file to the desired folder path should work.

Mac users example: `ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.39/include/pcre2.h /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.0/8.0.16_1/include/php/ext/pcre/pcre2.h`

Syntax : `ln -s <path-to-file> <path-to-be-put>`

This should work.